# creating parent task to call subproject tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to create a task in the parent **build.gradle** file that calls tasks from the subproject in this specific order.
This is my task definition in the **build.gradle** file and the tasks for each subproject are defined and working.  I can call each individual task from the command line.
I want to be able to call this parent task from the command line and it do all of the subproject tasks in the order defined.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task buildAll (dependsOn: 
    [ project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage,
      project(':load').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage,
      project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage,
      project(':load').loadPackage
    ])
```

When I run this task from the command line I get the error:

> Could not get unknown property 'remoteLoadCleanCompileStage' for
>   project ':loadRemote' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Is this not allowed in gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `buildAll` task definition in a `projectsEvaluated` clause. Indeed, when you are defining your task in parent build, the subprojects have not been analized so their tasks are not yet known.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    task buildAll (dependsOn:
            [ project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage,
              project(':load').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage,
              project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage,
              project(':load').loadPackage
            ])    
}
```

Explanations here :
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:projectsEvaluated(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: That created 1 of the ear files but not the second yet it ran successfully?

Comment: when executing task 'buildAll' : could you see all your needed remote* tasks from subprojects executed ?  if so , the initial question/issue is solved, you should open another issue for this new problem, I  think.